# Как сделать обтекание блока блоком?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/1gco0s0f Как сделать чтобы класс q2 не входил в q1 а обтекал его как текст. Но без применения float https://jsfiddle.net/1gco0s0f/1/ - не так

```css
.q1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.q2{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="q1"></div>
<div class="q2">q</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать свойство `shape-outside` и как пример:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 30px auto;
}
div:not(.wrapper) {
  shape-outside: ellipse(100px 200px at 50% 50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
  float: left;
  background-color: lighten(purple, 60);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis impedit libero esse odio excepturi fuga est ut itaque a quod suscipit, rerum asperiores. Consequuntur voluptates illo rerum recusandae pariatur asperiores, aspernatur, saepe ipsum error dolorem, quod inventore possimus modi deleniti tenetur et officiis. Nemo ab in totam ratione sequi error, ea dolorum repudiandae omnis, eaque facere impedit fugiat. Dolorum distinctio autem sequi enim quidem esse accusamus repudiandae voluptatum nobis, velit, molestiae. Eaque maiores, harum. Saepe esse repellendus sint. Labore provident optio quis commodi quod quaerat quo similique perspiciatis libero facere. Suscipit odit quas nemo, enim laudantium, provident repellendus natus nostrum facilis expedita adipisci qui, harum minus quidem officia cupiditate repellat ut praesentium. Possimus corporis, error atque ex adipisci, illum suscipit pariatur saepe impedit aliquam amet eos reiciendis quidem hic, nisi. Sint nobis modi, nesciunt quasi placeat quia. Veniam inventore corrupti quisquam illum debitis vitae accusamus nobis alias cum iste error magnam, cupiditate earum! Incidunt at consequuntur, rem ipsa odio ipsum deleniti repudiandae blanditiis harum ut in, fugit officia rerum ad, corporis dolore! Commodi repellendus esse quibusdam enim qui totam ipsum, consequuntur officia vel dolores, quod corrupti eveniet maiores minus explicabo, sapiente ratione doloribus laboriosam impedit nesciunt a obcaecati quam veritatis! Placeat, velit possimus delectus, atque voluptate iste alias illo, dolor odit ipsa facere quibusdam? Non omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores tempore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis impedit libero esse odio excepturi fuga est ut itaque a quod suscipit, rerum asperiores. Consequuntur voluptates illo rerum recusandae pariatur asperiores, aspernatur, saepe ipsum error dolorem, quod inventore possimus modi deleniti tenetur et officiis. Nemo ab in totam ratione sequi error, ea dolorum repudiandae omnis, eaque facere impedit fugiat. Dolorum distinctio autem sequi enim quidem esse accusamus repudiandae voluptatum nobis, velit, molestiae. Eaque maiores, harum. Saepe esse repellendus sint. Labore provident optio quis commodi quod quaerat quo similique perspiciatis libero facere. Suscipit odit quas nemo, enim laudantium, provident repellendus natus nostrum facilis expedita adipisci qui, harum minus quidem officia cupiditate repellat ut praesentium. Possimus corporis, error atque ex adipisci, illum suscipit pariatur saepe impedit aliquam amet eos reiciendis quidem hic, nisi. Sint nobis modi, nesciunt quasi placeat quia. Veniam inventore corrupti quisquam illum debitis vitae accusamus nobis alias cum iste error magnam, cupiditate earum! Incidunt at consequuntur, rem ipsa odio ipsum deleniti repudiandae blanditiis harum ut in, fugit officia rerum ad, corporis dolore! Commodi repellendus esse quibusdam enim qui totam ipsum, consequuntur officia vel dolores, quod corrupti eveniet maiores minus explicabo, sapiente ratione doloribus laboriosam impedit nesciunt a obcaecati quam veritatis! Placeat, velit possimus delectus, atque voluptate iste alias illo, dolor odit ipsa facere quibusdam? Non omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores temporeNon omnis aliquid eveniet fuga labore dolores, autem blanditiis, dolorem error ex enim fugiat quisquam aut reprehenderit delectus, nihil accusamus eaque at odit natus accusantium sunt asperiores unde? Tempora dolorem, ad quidem quis adipisci dolores tempore</p>
</div>
```

Comment: это же всё равно `float:left;` и к тому же надо было бы сказать о поддержке `shape-outside` http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, второй блок делаем `display: inline`.

```css
.q1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.q2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="q1"></div>
<div class="q2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis impedit libero esse odio excepturi fuga est ut itaque a quod suscipit, rerum asperiores. Consequuntur voluptates illo rerum recusandae pariatur asperiores, aspernatur, saepe ipsum error
  dolorem, quod inventore possimus modi deleniti tenetur et officiis. Nemo ab in totam ratione sequi error, ea dolorum repudiandae omnis, eaque facere impedit fugiat. Dolorum distinctio autem sequi enim quidem esse accusamus repudiandae voluptatum nobis,
  velit, molestiae. Eaque maiores, harum. Saepe esse repellendus sint. Labore provident optio quis commodi quod quaerat quo similique perspiciatis libero facere. Suscipit odit quas nemo, enim laudantium, provident repellendus natus nostrum facilis expedita
  adipisci qui, harum minus quidem officia cupiditate repellat ut praesentium. Possimus corporis, error atque ex adipisci, illum suscipit pariatur saepe impedit aliquam amet eos reiciendis quidem hic, nisi. Sint nobis modi, nesciunt quasi placeat quia.
  Veniam inventore corrupti quisquam illum debitis vitae accusamus nobis alias cum iste error magnam, cupiditate earum! Incidunt at</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gco0s0f/11/).

Comment: вставляйте ваш код, который можно воспроизвести, в сниппет, чтобы не надо было уходить на сторонние песочницы.